# How to generate the rows of data points from a model?

Tags: graphics, curated-data, anatomy

Recently, I notice two interesting built-ins `AnatomyPlot3D`and `AnatomyData`. For instance,

```
Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Liver"]["Graphics3D"]
```

[image]

Now I would like to know :

Is it possible to generate a set of cross-section of the liver model?

[image]

---

#### My trial for liver model

```
meshModel = Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Liver"]["MeshRegion"]
pointCloud = MeshCoordinates[meshModel];

liverSections = 
  SortBy[
    Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], IntegerPart[#[[3]]]} &, 
        GatherBy[pointCloud, IntegerPart[Last@#] &], {2}], 
    #[[1, -1]] &];

Graphics3D[Line /@ liverSections[[1 ;; 157 ;; 3]]]
```

[image]

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: @IgorRivin In fact, I would like to extract the cross-sections of the above liver model. However, the rows of data points generated by my trial are **unordered**.

Comment: In MMa 11 there's `AnatomyPlot3D` with the `ClipPlanes` option, as in `AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Liver"], 
 ClipPlanes -> 
  InfinitePlane[{{-3, -123, 1226}, {17, -143, 1226}, {-3, -143, 
     1206}}]]`. Might that help?